# How to handle errors in Phalcon\Mvc\Model::afterCreate

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon

I have a model that, once saved on the database needs to do some further operations, say for example upload a thumbnail somewhere. The best way to do that is to override `Phalcon\Mvc\Model::afterCreate` method and put there the code for the upload.

Now, suppose that the upload operation fails: what is the best way to return an error from `afterCreate` (and eventually notify the controller about that)?

Comment: Use [appendMessage()](https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html) method.

Comment: @AntonPelykh so the only way to check for errors is to see whether model::getMessages() is empty or not?

Comment: It's "Phalcon way" to receive the messages from model.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using ORM.

Try this:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $pedido = new MyApp\Models\PedidoItem();
    $pedido->daleBR = 123;
    $pedido->save();

    print_r($pedido->getMessages());exit;

}
```